# Toggle div depending on positon on page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a single scrolling page with a menu tucked away at the side. I want to toggle menu depending on the position on the page. I've managed to check the position and hide/show the menu at the appropriate locations but this will only work on page load. I need to the menu to be constantly active and toggle itself as the user scrolls down the page. Is this possible with jquery/js? This is my code so far:

```
var nav = $(".nav-links").offset();
var about = $("#page-about").offset();
var location = $("#page-location").offset();
var amenities = $("#page-amenities").offset();
var art = $("#page-art").offset();
var availabilities = $("#page-availabilities").offset();
var contact = $("#page-contact").offset();

console.log("amenities position " + amenities.top);
console.log("nav position " + nav.top);

if (about.top < nav.top) {
    $('.nav-links').css("display", "none");
}

if (location.top < nav.top) {
    $('.nav-links').css("display", "none");
}

if (amenities.top < nav.top) {
    $('.nav-links').css("display", "block");
}

if (art.top < nav.top) {
    $('.nav-links').css("display", "none")
}

if (availabilities.top < nav.top) {
    $('.nav-links').css("display", "none")
}

if (contact.top < nav.top) {
    $('.nav-links').css("display", "block")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to recheck the position each time the user scrolls. You can do this with an onScroll event

```
$(document).on('scroll', function () {
    // toggle code goes here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use scrollSpy from Twitter.Bootstrap, or something similar:

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy